# How to mocktest GeoIP location?

Tags: python, geolocation, geoip, ip-geolocation

We're looking at using the MaxMind GeoIP library for geolocating IP addresses, but I'm wondering how to even test if it is working?

For example, if our datacenter has an IP address in WA, but I want to mock as if I were in Montana, how would I test that?